# XSLT:Injecting values from one XML element into another XML element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working with a problem and was wondering how than can be done using XSLT(1.0). I have combined the data from 2 XML files into a single one. I have to inject values from one XML node into the other. Since my XML files are pretty big, I don't have to luxury of of creating elements in the XSLT. I would simply like to somehow map them from one *data1* elements to *data2* elements.

**Input:**

```
<combinedData>
<data1>
    <element1>
        <id>12</id>
        <name>Tony Green</name>
        <address>Home Address</address>
    </element1>
</data1>
<data2>
    <element1>
        <element2>
            <element3>
                <IdOfPerson></IdOfPerson>
                <NameOfPerson></NameOfPerson>
                <addressOfPerson></addressOfPerson>
            </element3>
        </element2>
    </element1>        
</data2>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<data2>
<element1>
    <element2>
        <element3>
            <IdOfPerson>12</IdOfPerson>
            <NameOfPerson>Tony Green</NameOfPerson>
            <addressOfPerson>Home Address</addressOfPerson>
        </element3>
    </element2>
</element1>
```

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy `data2`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//data2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Use a specific template for the child nodes of `element3`. I am assuming that you want to copy the data from the lower-case nodes of the same name of `data1/element1`:

```
<xsl:template match="element3/node()">
  <xsl:variable name="name-without-of-person" select="substring-before(name(), 'OfPerson')" />
  <xsl:variable name="lower-case" select="translate($name-without-of-person, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
  <!-- copy the original node -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- XSLT 1.0 does not support XPath queries that are dynamically generated,
         therefore, .../element1/$lower-case does not work.
         However, using a predicate with a name() query works -->
    <xsl:value-of select="/combinedData/data1/element1/*[name()=$lower-case]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```